# Find duplicats and display in new datagridview using Linq

Tags: vb.net, excel, csv, datagridview

I have two datagridviews:

**DataGridView1:**
This is generated from a csv file with this code:

```
For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\path\test.csv")
                Form1.DataGriView1.Rows.Add(line.Split(";"))
 Next
```

The.csv file has this format:

12345;SOME TEXT;2000000;12345678901;2014-07-31;

23456;SOME TEXT;2000000;10987654321;2014-07-11;

**DataGridView2**
This is generated from an excel file with this code:

```
 Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
            Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

            MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection _
                ("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source='C:\Users\path\excel.xls'; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
            MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter _
                    ("select * from [Sheet$]", MyConnection)
            DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
            MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
            Form1.DataGridView2.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
            MyConnection.Close()
```

The Excel document has 6 columns, with headers.

[image: This is how the datagridview are named]

### The question:

I need to find duplicates and display the data in a third gridview. Specifically, I want to see if the value in column column1 in DataGridView1 are in column polnr in DataGridView2. If it does, I want the entire line from DataGridView copied to DataGridView3

I'm using this code today, but the problem is that it's too slow...

Dim rowlist As New ArrayList
    Dim dgv3row As New DataGridViewRow

```
For Each dgv1row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    For Each dgv2row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows

        If dgv1row.Cells("Column1").Value = dgv2row.Cells("polnr").Value Then

            For Each dgvcell As DataGridViewCell In dgv1row.Cells
                rowlist.Add(dgvcell.Value)
            Next

            If rowlist.Count > 0 Then
                Dim dgv3rowindex As Integer = DataGridView3.Rows.Add()

                dgv3row = DataGridView3.Rows(dgv3rowindex)

                For Each dgv3cell As DataGridViewCell In dgv3row.Cells
                    dgv3cell.Value = rowlist(dgv3cell.ColumnIndex)
                Next

                rowlist.Clear()
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

**My question is:** Is it a faster way to do it? Like LINQ or something?

Comment: Why are you adding the information into rowlist then dgv3row when you could just add it directly to dgv3row skipping rowlist?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to query for duplicate records:

```
Dim dupRecords = (From data1 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                          Join data2 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
                          On data1.Cells("Column1").Value Equals data2.Cells("polnr").Value
                          Select data2).ToList
```

Then iterate through the duplicate row results and add to the 3rd datagridview.  The below assumes the columns are already created in the 3rd datagridview:

```
Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

For Each row In dupRecords
   For cellIndex As Integer = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 1
     DataGridView3.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(cellIndex).Value = _
        row.Cells(cellIndex).Value
   Next cellIndex
   rowIndex += 1
Next row
```